# Show "Page X of Y" only if there are multiple pages?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, counters

I'm trying to add a line in the header to be "Page X of Y", but only if there are multiple pages. My main problem is how to format the if statement. So far I have

```
    \ifx \pageref{LastPage} 1
    \relax
\else
    \fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fi
```

I think it's the first line that is problematic, as the rest seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try loading the **refcount** package and using

```
\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1
```

instead of `\ifx\pageref{LastPage}1` (which is wrong for other reasons). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/latex-how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number).

"Full code":

```
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1
  \else
    Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}%
  \fi
}
```

However, Marco's suggestion to use **zref** seems to be better:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[totpages,user]{zref}
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \ifnum\ztotpages=1
  \else
    Page \thepage\ of \ztotpages
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo Ah, yes! I'll add to my answer.

Comment: For information, I ran into trouble when I tried using `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndDocument` with the `lastpage` package loaded. I kept getting *Page 3 of 2*. The `zref-totpages` solved my problem and seems more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solution of egreg but it doesn't work. With the hint of [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)(see comment below) it works well (see the example below)

I used the `zref` packages which is recommended by `lastpage`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[totpages,lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{
\ifthenelse{\ztotpages = 1}{}{\fancyhead[R]{Page \thepage\ of \zpageref{LastPage}}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

Text \zpageref{LastPage} 

\clearpage
TExt
\end{document}
```

Example of egreg:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{refcount,lastpage}
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1\relax%
    \else
       Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}%
  \fi%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

Text 

\clearpage
TExt
\end{document}
```

**@egreg: Sorry**

Comment: egreg's solution works using `\fancyhead[R]{
\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=1
    \relax
\else
    Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
\fi
}`

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Thanks. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the xstring package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xstring}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\IfEq{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}{1}{}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```