# How can I calculate the difference of 2 counters (pageref)?

Tags: page-numbering, counters, calculations

- How can I calculate the difference between 2 counters (like page numbers), so that `pdfLateX` outputs "3" in the last line of my example?
- and how could I calculate the difference between the "current" page (where the calculation is printed) and `\pageref{A}` (without explicitly defining `\label{B}`)?

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Here is label A \label{A}

\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\newpage

Here is label B \label{B}

There are \pageref{B}-\pageref{A} pages between labels A and B. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the page counter is incremented asynchronously some time during the output routine. Therefore you can't be sure that the difference is correct when you don't have a second label. An exception is directly after a `\clearpage`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [refcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package can extract the number from a reference. That only works for `arabic` page numbers, of course. And there must not be any `\addtocounter{page}{...}` or `\setcounter{page}{...}` between A and B. For those more complicated situations, `\theCurrentPage` of the [pageslts](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) package can be used.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{pageslts}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

Here is label A. \label{A}

\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\newpage

Here is label B \label{B}

\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=\getpagerefnumber{B}\relax%
\advance\@tempcnta by -\getpagerefnumber{A}%
% (maybe
% \advance\@tempcnta by -1%
% depending on your definition of "between")
\xdef\pagedifference{\the\@tempcnta}%
\makeatother

There are \pagedifference~pages between labels A and B.

\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=-\getpagerefnumber{A}\relax%
\advance\@tempcnta by \thepage%
% (maybe \advance\@tempcnta by -1, depending on definition of "between")
\xdef\pagedifference{\the\@tempcnta}%
\makeatother

There are \pagedifference~pages between labels A and the current page.


\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

Here is page \thepage{} (the \theCurrentPage{}.~page).
\xdef\mypageA{\theCurrentPage}

\newpage
text
\newpage
text
\addtocounter{page}{10}
Just added 10 to the page number here.

\newpage

Here is page \thepage{} (the \theCurrentPage{}.~page).
\xdef\mypageB{\theCurrentPage}

\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=\mypageB\relax%
\advance\@tempcnta by -\mypageA%
% (maybe \advance\@tempcnta by -1, depending on definition of "between")
\xdef\pagedifference{\the\@tempcnta}%
\makeatother

There are \pagedifference~pages between page A and the current page B.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get lots of warnings with this solution "Package undolabl Warning: Label `pagesLTS.arabic' overridden on input line x", any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @L.Nielsen Do you get the warning when compiling the given example, or when compiling your LaTeX document?

Answer (score 9):

With the limitations already explained by Stephen, you can define

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\pagedifference}[2]{%
  \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{#2}-\getpagerefnumber{#1}\relax}
```

so that

```
\pagedifference{A}{B}
```

will give the number of pages from that in which `\label{A}` occurs to that where `\label{B}` occurrs. This needs (as usual when using the `\label`-`\ref` system) a couple of compilations to stabilize.

Answer (score 3):

A TeX-y solution:

```
\newcount{\temp}
\temp=\pageref{B}
\advance\temp by -\pageref{A}\relax

There are \the\temp\ pages between labels A and B.

\newpage
\temp=\arabic{page}
\advance\temp by -\pageref{A}\relax

There are \the\temp\ pages between this one and label A.
```

A more LaTeX-y one:

```
\newcounter{temp}
\setcounter{temp}{\pageref{B}}
\addtocounter{temp}{-\pageref{A}}

There are \arabic{temp}\ pages between labels A and B.

\newpage
\setcounter{temp}{\arabic{page}}
\addtocounter{temp}{-\pageref{A}}

There are \arabic{temp}\ pages between this one and label A.
```

Comment: @Stephen, Ant: `\pageref` isn't expandable when `hyperref` (a very common package after all) is loaded. This will break its usage inside the above assignments. It is better to use the `zref` package and to explicit as for the plain page number only. There should be some answers here which show that. The `refcount` package mentioned in the other answer is also good for this purpose.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Not only `hyperref` but also `babel` (as used in the MWE of the OP) causes a problem: `\documentclass{scrbook} \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} \begin{document} \label{B} \newcount{\temp} \temp=\pageref{B} \end{document}` results in `\temp=\count90 ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \protect l.11 \temp=\pageref {B} ?`. I had not expected that. Thus, Ant's code works, but not with `babel` (or `hyperref` or with non-arabic page-numbers or when the page-number is not-continuous). There are always new ways to break things in TeX ;-) .

Comment: @Stephen, re breaking things in TeX: indeed...!