# Page numbering range with first - last page

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering

I've been trying to output a page range, including the first and last page numbers of the chapter (e.g. "p. 20 - 39"). I've been using the `\pageref{LastPage}` command for the last page of the chapter, but can't find a way to output the first page (ideally a command such as `\pageref{FirstPage}`). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We usually use two `\label` commands related to the chapter number. Please post an MWE and we can try an experiment or two to get it work in your example.

Comment: you seem to think that `lastpage` gives you the last page of the _chapter_ ... it doesn’t – it gives you the last page of the whole document.  (feel free to ignore if i’ve misunderstood what you said.)

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the comments `LastPage` gives the last page of the document and thus may not be very helpful for what you're trying to achieve. I suggest defining a label at the beginning of each chapter and then using those labels to get the pages between them. Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\newcounter{rangeendpage}
\newcounter{rangepages}
\newcommand{\setpagecounters}[2]{%
    \setcounter{rangeendpage}{\pageref{#2}}
    \addtocounter{rangeendpage}{-1}
    \setcounter{rangepages}{\pageref{#2}}
    \addtocounter{rangepages}{-\pageref{#1}}
    \makeatletter
    \if\therangepages0%
        \setcounter{rangeendpage}{\pageref{#2}}
        \setcounter{rangepages}{1}
    \fi
    \makeatother
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{ch1}
    \setpagecounters{ch1}{ch2}
    This chapter contains pages \pageref{ch1} to \arabic{rangeendpage}, which is \arabic{rangepages} in total.

    \Blindtext
    \Blindtext

    \chapter{Chapter 2}\label{ch2}
    \setpagecounters{ch2}{ch3}
    This chapter contains pages \pageref{ch2} to \arabic{rangeendpage}, which is \arabic{rangepages} in total.
    \blindtext

    \chapter{Chapter 3}\label{ch3}
    \setpagecounters{ch3}{LastPage}
    This chapter is the last and contains pages \pageref{ch3} to \arabic{rangeendpage}, which is \arabic{rangepages} in total.

\end{document}
```

which will produce output like this:

[image]

The example uses the `LastPage` for the very last chapter. It also takes care of the case where a chapter is only one page - see Chapter 3. Blank pages before the start of a new chapter are counted towards the previous chapter - see Chapter 1.

Comment: oh, just noticed something similar was already [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-of-2-counters-pageref)

Comment: This seems to work. Many thanks for your help!