# Print some document's statistics in preamble (eg. nb. of pages for each section)?

Tags: pdftex, automation, statistics

I'm searching for a way to get then print some statistics of my PhD thesis pdfLaTeX document in order to give some practical data to my supervisors on my writing progress (and also to help me get a better view of the project).

---

**The output I wish for :**

1. Memoir title page
2. Writing journal (one page displaying the document's statistics)
3. Content

or

1. Writing journal (one page displaying the document's statistics)
2. Memoir title page
3. Content

---

In this "Writing journal" I wish to display :

[X] Current date (checked with \today)

[X] Total number of pages (checked with Lastpage package)

[_] Total number of bibliographical references --> I found this : https://texblog.org/2012/04/16/counting-the-total-number-of/ but I don't know if this applies to the memoir class

[_] Number of pages for each section --> I found this : [How can I calculate the difference of 2 counters (pageref)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-of-2-counters-pageref/38143#38143) but it's designed to be displayed in header rather than in the preamble

That would be something like :

```
Date : 2020/09/15
Total number of pages : 240
Total number of references : 186

Introduction : 5 pages
Context : 15 pages
Corpus : 20 pages
Methodology : 40 pages
etc.
```

---

**Worst case scenario :**

I just python through my .tex or my .pdf file, get the data, print it in a .txt file and budle it alongside the pdf while sending it with an e-mail X-D

Comment: Egreg's solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38139/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-of-2-counters-pageref/38143#38143 has nothing to do with headers.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll look into that