# Automatically remove page number if document has only one page (but not if two)

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, page-numbering, zref

I write a lot of documents (agreements) based on `memoir` with the `article` option. Normal `pagestyle`is `plain` (page number centered in the footer). Sometimes a document is only one page long, and a page number is unnecessary.

It is not much work to put a `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle` (because `\maketitle` has hardcoded a `\thispagestyle{plain}` somewhere). But sometimes I forget this, and sometimes I add a word or two, and the document suddenly is two pages long. And it is of course much more fun to have LaTeX to do this automatically.

By borrowing some code from Ulrike Fisher’s answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4258/9632), I was able to defining this macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ifthen}
\usepackage[lastpage]{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop*{numpage}{\the\value{page}}
\zref@addprop{main}{numpage}
\newcommand{\oneormorepages}%
    {\ifthenelse{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{numpage}{1}>1}%
        {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}}%
    }
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\oneormorepages
\lipsum[1-60] %More than one page
%\lipsum[1]   % One page
\end{document}
```

Is there better and simpler solutions? For example one that does not involve additional packages?

To include the macro `\oneormorepages`in the text is a kludge. I can redefine `\maketitle`, but I am reluctant to that. Is there a better solution for integrating the test in the preamble? My goal is to include such test in a separate, private style- or class-file?

**EDIT**: And here is the result I have used until today. I patch `\maketitle` on the fly using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`, a package I load for other purposes in the ‘real’ document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}

%% No page number  if the document is a onepager
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\value{page} > \@ne
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\let\string\@multipage\relax}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\oneormorepages}{%
    \ifdefined\@multipage
        \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \else
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \fi
 }
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
    {\oneormorepages}{}{}
%% Change `plain` to `title` if you are using a `memoir` class
\makeatother


\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-60] %More than one page
%\lipsum[1]   % One page
\end{document}
```

*EDIT*: MWE is updated 28.09.2014 and improved based on comments from egreg and JFBU.

Thanks a lot for all help!

**FINAL EDIT 28.09.2014**

Based on the discussion in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203403/9632) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165941/9632) to another question, I  have a working solution not requiring any additional packages, working under KOMAscript and the standard classes  and surviving `\pagenumbering{Roman}`. As egreg has pointed out, it is still not fool proof, but I have tried postponing the tests by loading the `atendvi`- and `atveryend`-packages from the `oberdiek`-bundle, and using commands from those packages. Then the tests fail. So for the MWEs below, we have to trust `\AtEndDocument`. (At least for the time being).

Here are the MWEs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter % You may remove this line if you change\@ne to 1
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{page}=\@ne\thispagestyle{empty}{}\fi} % survives `\pagenumbering{Roman}`
\makeatother % You may remove this line if you change\@ne to 1
\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-6] % Turn on/off this line...
\end{document}
```

If you need Roman numbering, you may also load `zref-totpages`and change the test to:

```
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\ztotpages=\@ne\thispagestyle{empty}{}\fi}
```

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165888/9632), I have found a solution using `scrartcl`, `scrpage2` and `zref-totpages`, which also survives `\pagenumbering{Roman}`. You may make it more useful by adding additional code to the `false` or `true` parts of the test:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{zref-totpages,lipsum,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrplain}
\clearscrheadfoot
% You may use \@ne instead of 1 if you enclose the line in a `\makeatletter\makeatother`
\cfoot[\ifnum\ztotpages=1 \else\pagemark\fi]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % automatically remove page number in a document with this line
%\lipsum[1-6] % automatically keep page numbers in a document with this line
\end{document}
```

And finally, one for the standard classes, conditionally redefining the `plain`-pagestyle. (`let\ps@plain\ps@empty` did not work).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,zref-totpages}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
     \ifnum\ztotpages=\@ne\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@oddfoot\@empty
     \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty{}%
 \fi}
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-6] % Turn on/off this line...
\end{document}
```

Hopefully, it is useful.

Comment: If your documents all have a `\maketitle` line, then you can change its definition to have `\oneormoreside` instead of `\thispagestyle{plain}`. If they haven't it necessarily, say also `\AtBeginDocument{\oneormoreside}`.

Comment: You could get rid of the `ifthen` too package by using `\ifnum` instead of `\ifthen`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't require any extra packages or an extra `\label` at the end, but it does still write to the aux file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\value{page} > 1%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\xdef\string\@multipage\string{\string}}%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\oneormoreside}{\ifdefined\@multipage\else\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%
\maketitle
\oneormoreside

%\lipsum[1-60] %More than one page
\lipsum[1]   % One page
\end{document}
```

Since the information is written to the aux file you need two passes for it to work correctly.

Comment: Why not simply `\let\noexpand\@multipage\noexpand\@empty` as the token list to write in the aux file? `\xdef\@multipage{}` is not different from `\let\@multipage\@empty` and more efficient (`\xdef` serves no real purpose and `\def` would be the same: the aux file is not read inside a group). However there are many things that might make the test fail.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the helpful comments, both are improvements. When you say there are many things that might make the test fail, are you referring to the `\ifnum` test, the `\ifdefined` test or both?

Comment: Something can add to the document *after* what you've added with `\AtEndDocument`. It's uncommon, but it can happen. Just be aware of that.

Comment: @egreg I just checked and I need `\xdef`, well I only need `\gdef`, but for some reason it has to be global.

Comment: So `\global\let\noexpand...`

Comment: For me this works but if my document has more than 1 page the first  page doesn't get the number '1' instead it is plain. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @TimS. it requires two passes.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I ran two times but now I see result ;)

Answer (score 6):

You requested a solution without "extra packages". Here is a solution without `zref`, but it still needs `ifthen`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ifthen} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypagestyle}%
    {\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}>1}%
        {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}}%
    }
\mypagestyle

\lipsum[2-10] 

\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

P.S. Personally, I would prefer a solution like yours but with `lastpage` (http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage) instead of `zref`.

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but breaks if `\pagenumbering{Roman}` (see the answer referred to in my question). In addition, you have two commands in the text. But one vote for reducing the number of packages. I was not able defined a workable macro with `\lastpage`. `\refcount` was easier.

Answer (score 0):

Current LaTeX already automatically defines `\@abspage@last` via the `.aux` file. Two compilation runs are necessary but no additional package at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oneormorepages}{%
  \def\singelpage{1}%
  \ifx\singelpage\@abspage@last \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \else \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\maketitle
\oneormorepages
%\lipsum[1-60] % Several pages
\lipsum[1]     % Single page
%\newpage
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```