# How to use the total page count in a conditional expression?

Tags: conditionals, expansion

I would like to have different footer or page style depending on whether the document has one or more pages. I am not very experienced with TeX programming, so the answers [about "Comparing an argument to a string when argument is a result of a command with etoolbox"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24922/comparing-an-argument-to-a-string-when-argument-is-a-result-of-a-command-with-et/) did not help me much and ["When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter) is a bit complicated for me for the first time.

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}

\expandafter\ifstrequal{\pageref*{LastPage}}{1}{
  \pagestyle{empty}
  }{
  \pagestyle{plain}}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

I may keep experimenting.

Could someone show me a good way to do this, please?

Comment: You will find a solution in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56842/9632).

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Sveinung. An unaccepted answer there does exactly what i want, with **ifthen** package and `\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}>1}{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{empty}}` command. However, now i am trying to do the same with **etoolbox**, but i do not succeed. A straightforward replacement of `\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}>1}` with `\ifnumcomp{\pageref{LastPage}}{>}{1}` does not work.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, so I ended up the other solution. Cfr. my comments. Also, have look at egreg's comments and suggested improvements in the answer that I accepted.

Comment: The only problem for me is to convert `\pageref{LastPage}` to a number so that `\ifnumcomp` from **etoolbox** could use it. I saw it claimed that **etoolbox** can do everything **ifthen** can, but i do not find how.

Comment: I struggled with the same problem, and ended up asking the community too. Another problem is that '\thispagestyle{empty}' is hardcoded in '\maketitle'. You may try to conditionally redefine the pagestyles based on the test of number of pages.

Comment: I've posted [another question about this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203425/how-to-translate-ifthenelse-from-ifthen-to-etoolbox).

Comment: See Heiko Oberdiek's [answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165888/9632),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `lastpage` you can use `totcount` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{page}

\begin{document}

\ifnumcomp{\totvalue{page}}{>}{1}{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{empty}}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will take 2 compilation runs to settle down.

Comment: I'm not sure but if any other style that changes the text area size instead of `plain`, this might not settle down at all. I can't think of any example now but I think we can cook up one.

Comment: Remember that this macro has to be used *after* `\maketitle`.

Comment: I hope, that nobody resets the number of pages somewhere right before the end of the document, such that it `totcount` accidentally has the value of `1` whereas there are definitely more than 1 page

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem regarding page number in documents, and found several solutions.

By borrowing some code from Ulrike Fisher’s answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4258/9632) I was able to defining this macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,ifthen}
\usepackage[lastpage]{zref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop*{numpage}{\the\value{page}}
\zref@addprop{main}{numpage}
\newcommand{\oneormorepages}%
    {\ifthenelse{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{numpage}{1}>1}%
        {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}}%
    }
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\oneormorepages
\lipsum[1-60] %More than one page
%\lipsum[1]   % One page
\end{document}
```

Here is the result I have used until today. I patch `\maketitle` on the fly using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`, a package I load for other purposes in the ‘real’ document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}

%% No page number  if the document ai a onepager
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\value{page} > \@ne
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\global\let\string\@multipage\relax}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\oneormorepages}{%
    \ifdefined\@multipage
        \thispagestyle{plain}%
    \else
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \fi
 }
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
    {\thispagestyle{plain}}%
    {\oneormorepages}{}{}
%% Change `plain` to `title` if you are using a `memoir` class
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-60] % More than one page
%\lipsum[1]   % One page
\end{document}
```

As egreg emphasises in the comment below (and in a comment to the original answer), the solution is not hundred per cent fool proof (f.ex. it does not work under `scrartcl`). I have now corrected the errors jfbu has pinpointed.

Today I was even able to find two additional solutions that does not need patching *etc*.:

Based on the discussion in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203403/9632) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165941/9632) to another question, I  have tinkered together a working solution not requiring any additional packages, and working under KOMAscript and the standard classes. It survives `\pagenumbering{Roman}`. As egreg has pointed out, it is still not fool proof, but I have tried postponing the tests by loading the `atendvi`- and `atveryend`-packages from the `oberdiek`-bundle and using commands from those packages. Then the tests fail. So for the MWEs below, we have to trust `\AtEndDocument`.

Here are the MWEs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter % You may remove this line if you change\@ne to 1
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\value{page]=\@ne\thispagestyle{empty}{}\fi} % survives `\pagenumbering{Roman}`
\makeatother % You may remove this line if you change\@ne to 1
\title{Test}
\author{Test Testson}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-6] % Turn on/off this line...
\end{document}
```

If you need Roman numbering, you may also load `zref-totpages`and change the test to:

```
\AtEndDocument{\ifnum\ztotpages=\@ne\thispagestyle{empty}{}\fi}
```

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165888/9632), I have found a solution using `scrartcl`, `scrpage2` and `zref-totpages`, which also survives `\pagenumbering{Roman}`. You may at additional code to the `false`and `true` parts of the test:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{zref-totpages,lipsum,scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrplain}
\clearscrheadfoot
% You may use \@ne instead of 1 if you enclose the line in a `\makeatletter\makeatother`
\cfoot[\ifnum\ztotpages=1 \else\pagemark\fi]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % automatically remove page number in a document with this line
%\lipsum[1-6] % automatically keep page numbers in a document with this line
\end{document}
```

Hopefully, it is useful.

Comment: It's rather common for Germans to translate *Seite* into *side*, but it's wrong, although the words are cognate. I don't think the second method is completely foolproof, because `\AtEndDocument` is not necessarily executed at the last page.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solutions, but the second one looks a bit too low-level for me (i might be not the only person to look at my document class source code). Using **ifthen**, i could also make it work, but now i am trying to convert it to **etoolbox** staying "high-level", see my comment to my question.

Comment: @Sveinung you can replace `\string{\string}` with `{}`.

Comment: you can use `\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\let\string\@multipage\relax}` and besides your `MWE` is with `article` but uses `title` and not `plain` thus it does not work as expected in the single page case. Also are you sure you don't want your patch something like `\newcommand{\oneormoreside}{\ifdefined\@multipage\thispagestyle{title}\else\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}
` else the `\thispagestyle {title}` disappears entirely.

Comment: @Sveinung you can drop `%` in situations such as `ifdefined\@multipage%`, or `\else%`, `\fi%`, and on the other hand it would better with `> 1` rather than `> 1%` because the end of line space will stop `TeX` scan for a number, which is good practice, here it stops on encountering the  `\immediate\write` thing, in other contexts it could lead to unexpected hard to debug problems. Or still better, replace `1` by `\@ne`.

Comment: @Sveinung `\thispagestyle{empty}` should be `\thispagestyle{empty}%` in macro `\oneormoreside`