# How to translate \ifthenelse from "ifthen" to "etoolbox"?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

Trying to make conditional expressions that inspect the total page count of the document (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203403/how-to-use-the-total-page-count-in-a-conditional-expression)), I've found this solution using `ifthen` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\pageref{LastPage}>1}{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{empty}}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

I would like to try to use `etoolbox` instead of `ifthen` because it looks like now it is a more commonly used package. My following attempt does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}

\ifnumcomp{\pageref{LastPage}}{>}{1}{\pagestyle{plain}}{\pagestyle{empty}}

\lipsum[2-13]

\end{document}
```

So, how can i do this with `etoolbox`

Comment: Probably this should be a Community Wiki.

Comment: My other question has a couple of acceptable answers now, but i hesitate to delete this question because i am still curious if it is possible to use something like `\pageref{LastPage}` in a conditional from **etoolbox**.

Comment: Asking for improvements in working solutions should be fully legitimate.

Comment: Why don't you use \ifnum\pageref{LastPage}>1 \pagestyle{plain} \else\pagestyle{empty}\fi (no package needed)?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the result of `\pageref` as a number and to do number comparision -- neither with ifthen or with etoolbox. It could also contain text or formatting instruction or be a roman number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, can i do string comparison with `\pageref`? If yes, how?

Comment: You can compare two \pagerefs, e.g. with etoolbox `\ifdefstrequal{\pageref{a}}{\pageref{b}}{yes}{no}`. When I really want to be on the safe side I use the zref package to get real numbers to compare.

Answer (score 9):

The main problem is that `\pageref{LastPage}` cannot be used in the argument of `\ifthenelse`, nor in the `etoolbox` functions, because it's only good for *printing* the page reference.

One has to use a different approach, with the safer package `zref-lastpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{% this must be executed after the aux file has been input
  \ifnum\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}>1
    \pagestyle{plain}%
  \else
    \pagestyle{empty}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
x

%\clearpage
%y

\end{document}
```

Instead of `\ifnum` the corresponding `etoolbox` function can be used

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{% this must be executed after the aux file has been input
  \ifnumcomp{\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{page}{0}}{>}{1}
    {\pagestyle{plain}}
    {\pagestyle{empty}}%
}
\makeatother
```

However this still requires `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and `\AtBeginDocument` like the code above, because we have to ensure the code is executed *after* the `.aux` file has been read in.

Uncommenting the lines with `%` will show the page number on both pages; as it is no page number will be printed.