# store page number of current page into a variable and reuse it later

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use \pageref{foo} as a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number)

i'd like to store the current page number into a variable and reuse it later:

% Roman numbers
list of contents
list of figures

```
variable lastpagenumber = this.page.currentnumber
```

% Arabic numbers
contents

% Literature & Appendix
pagenumbering: Roman

```
start with page (lastpagenumber)
```

if you could show me the defining, setting and reusing of the variable that'd be great.

Comment: Does [How to use `\pageref{foo}` as a number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4180/5764) solve your question? It uses [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to store the page reference in a counter (variable). Give some feedback.

Comment: First of all: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It doesn't get quite clear to me what you aim at with your question, ans as I look at the comments to the answer below, others seem to have the same problem. Maybe you explain a bit more, what you want to reach. Maybe also have a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page.

Comment: Following up on on @BenediktBauer's comment, you need to tell us how you want to use this infomation later in the document.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\label` on the page in question and `\pageref` where you want to later reference it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\label{I want to remember this first page}

\lipsum[6-20]

I've remembered the page \pageref{I want to remember this first page}

\end{document}
```

Do note that you must *compile* your document twice to get the page references correct.

Here's an example which let's you put material in the header and footer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\label{I want to remember this first page}

\lipsum[6-20]

I've remembered the question \pageref{I want to remember this first page}

Check out the bottom of the page:
\cfoot{My reference to the first page\pageref{I want to remember this first page}}

\end{document}
```

I've called the package `fancyhdr` to accomplish this, but make sure you don't call `\pagestyle{empty}` as I did in the first example or you won't see anything.

Comment: ooh you beat me by less than a second, I'll delete my answer which was the same, so +1:-)

Comment: doesn't work. just prints the page number into the text area instead of the footer area. any method to convert the string to int?

Comment: Give a MWE so we can better see what you're trying to do and better understand the issue you're facing

Comment: Make sure you get rid of the`\pagestyle{empty}`.  That might be your problem if you too literally copied my example.  Sorry (my bad) I should have removed that line from my MWE

Comment: that does not support automatic incrementing of numbers. isn't there any way to convert the string (returned by pageref) to an integer?

Comment: Have you tried:
`\setcounter{testcnt}{\pageref{I want to remember this first page}}`

Comment: @ndrizza: consider also `\getpagerefnumber` from the `refcount` package instead of `\pageref`

Comment: not working either... i'll go for the manual solution.

Comment: So ... this is 1/2 way working for me.  I made a unique label on the page that I want to remember, I later refer to the page ... and the actual page number is correctly printed ... but, it somehow generates a LINK to the starting page of the CHAPTER that contains the page ... which is several pages off.   Any ideas of what to correct ?

Comment: @RichWalt It's hard to say without seeing your code.  Trim you document down to a manageable size such that the *error* is still duplicated and then post it as a question here.

Comment: @A.Ellett ... Yeah ... that's probably the only way to solve this issue.  Done: posted at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642782/.  Thanks if you're able to take a look at this.