# How to pass (or temporary change the format of) the value of \pageref{foo}?

Tags: page-numbering, xstring

This is related to [How to use \pageref{foo} as a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number) but slightly different:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand*\thepage{A\arabic{page}}
%This type of pagenumbering is required by the customer
\begin{document}
  This document consist of \pageref{LastPage} pages.\\  
  %Needed in this case: "This document consist of 4 pages."
  %(Length of document varies each time of course)
  \blindtext[15]
  \label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

I need a way to convert e.g. "A4" into "4" without breaking the format of the pagenumbering in the document.
I tried to use \StrSubstitute but it failed, because it does attempt to replace something in the \pageref command instead doing the operation
with its value "A4".
I also tried every proposed solution in [How to use \pageref{foo} as a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number) but without success.

How would you tackle this problem? I don't seem to understand correctly how to read the value from \pageref and work with it (i.e. eliminate the "A"
with \StrSubstitute).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: easiest is to use the lastpage package which makes a special internal \label on the past page that always uses a numeric form even if \thepage is unsuitable

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It gives me "This document consist of A4 pages."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `totpages` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand*\thepage{A\arabic{page}}

\usepackage{totpages}
%This type of pagenumbering is required by the customer
\begin{document}
  This document consist of \ref{TotPages} pages.\\  
  %Needed in this case: "This document consist of 4 pages."
  %(Length of document varies each time of course)
  \blindtext[15]
  \label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To subtract the title page:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand*\thepage{A\arabic{page}}

\usepackage{totpages}
\begin{document}
    \addtocounter{TotPages}{-1}
  This document consist of \ref{TotPages} pages.

  \blindtext[15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `totcount` does not always report the correct page counter value. The page counter is an unreliable friend! You should use an associated total counter from `xassoccnt` for this ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's "Schleichwerbung" :)

Comment: No, it's a "Hinweis" :D

Comment: Answer 1 works in principle. Unfortunately I forgot, that my document has a titlepage, that shall not be counted. So I am off by one page ("The document consist of 25 pages" instead of 24+title).

Comment: @MartinBrennecke See my edit. If you need more control of what's happening, look into the `xassoccnt` package mentioned in Christian Hupfers comment above.

Comment: @samcarter thanks a lot! That works just fine for now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not redefine `\thepage` but `\pagemark`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{A\thepage}}

\begin{document}
  This document consist of \pageref{LastPage} pages.

  \blindtext[15]
  \label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunately this breaks my header in the original document, which is more like so: "page {\thepage} of {\pageref*{foo}}".

Comment: @MartinBrennecke: You can/should replace `\thepage` by `\pagemark` in the document header or simply add `A` in front of `\thepage`.

Comment: Thought about that too. Decided to go by \renewcommand*\thepage{A\arabic{page}} to get a nice looking TOC like this:      `Inhaltsverzeichnis

Anhang A – Expertenbericht 
Zusammenfassung    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . A3

A-1   Prüfnachweise und weitere Dokumentation    .  .  .  .  .  .  . A6
A-1.1 Zertifizierungsumfang     .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . A7` I guess this won't work with \pagemark ?

Comment: Darn. This looks like crap without CR. But I hope you'll get the idea anyways...