# Where does \label write to?

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, cjk, xecjk

Sorry this is a basic question.
I do not know where does \label write the data to?

In my previous installation of MikTex 2.9 I can use
`\CJKnumber{\ref{X}}` to reference a previously defined number X and `\CJKnumber` will
change this number into Chinese character.
But the present installation cannot.
It said the number `\ref{X}` is undefined.
Therefore I want to check whether does `\ref{X}` really exists.

Comment: Provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) please, otherwise we can't guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I don't suppose you just need to compile a second time so that `\ref{X}` is defined?  (And `\label` is written to the `aux` file, but this hasn't changed for a long time, so changing to MikTeX 2.9 wouldn't have broken it.)

Comment: You should look at [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount). Possible duplicate: [How to use `\pageref{foo}` as a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4180/5764)

Comment: \label write into the aux file. The should be a \newlabel entry. If the aux file is not there, check if you have some clean option in your compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `\CJKnumber{\ref{X}}` cannot work is as follows. While `\CJKnumber` expects its argument to be a number, the `\ref` macro isn't expandable; therefore, `\CJKnumber` is not receiving a number to work on. (Jargon-Alert: "expandability" and "expansion" of macros is at the very core of the TeX programming language.)

What's the remedy? I suggest you employ the [refcount](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package and its `\getrefnumber` macro; in contrast to `\ref{<some_label>}`, `\getrefnumber{<some_label>}` *is* expandable. The upshot is that `\CJKnumber{\getrefnumber{<some_label>}}` works as expected.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{xeCJK,CJKnumb}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{refcount} % for \getrefnumber macro

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{equation}{554} % just for this example
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:something}

\ref{eq:something}
\CJKnumber{\getrefnumber{eq:something}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico your method indeed work. But why could the same file be successful in previous installation?

Comment: @nana - Regarding your follow-up question: Not having any connections to the maintainer of the `CJKnumb` package, I'm afraid I have no answer. I do know that the non-expandability of the`\ref` macro has been a constant feature for many years (and, more likely, *decades*).